# How to know the frequency of persited row in a database Table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working on a web application with a postgresql database. We have a table that contains rows persisted by another app.
These rows arrived from Kafka everyday.
This is the structure of this table:

```
creation_date        status
...
...
20/07/2021 11:47    CREATED
20/07/2021 11:47    CREATED
20/07/2021 11:47    TREATED
20/07/2021 11:45    TREATED
20/07/2021 11:45    TREATED
20/07/2021 11:44    TREATED
20/07/2021 11:44    TREATED
...
...
19/07/2021 16:20    TREATED
19/07/2021 16:16    TREATED
...
...
19/07/2021 08:10    TREATED
19/07/2021 08:08    ERROR
19/07/2021 08:05    TREATED
19/07/2021 08:04    TREATED
19/07/2021 08:02    ERROR
...
...
```

so everyday we have new rows persisted .

My issue is that I want to use these rows to know what is the interval where we receive rows everyday
(ex: between 7am and 9am or 8am and 10am...).
I want to know this interval in order to execute everyday an SQL query to count the rows in this X interval.
If the count is 0 I will send an alert to say there is a problem and we don't receive events today  else everything is okay.
Do you have any idea how I can know this time interval using the previous data?

Regards.

Comment: And what results would you want?  And if your receiving rows 24h a day, what do you mean the interval where you receive rows?

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for your time. sometimes we receive events only between 6am and 10am we don't receive anything the rest of the day. i will modify my question i have to remove 24/24

Comment: Could you please provide some examples of what you're looking for?  (i.e., how is the `status` column related to the calculation?)

Comment: hello @richyen thank you for your time. no the column status is not related to the calculation. what im looking for is an sql query that return de time intervall where the events arrived everyday. ex between  9am and 10am or 6am and  7am...